Using script Variables as a Background Image Source in HTML
I'm trying to use a script variable as a background image source for a body element in HTML, but no solution on the internet has worked.
<script>
    #Some conditions and variables that form the final variable
    var backimage = 'images/' + image + '.jpg'
  </script>
<style>
      body {
        background: url(#backimage varable here) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        ...

I tried using code like this
Script:
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('paragraph').style.background = 'url('+iimage+')';

HTML:
        background: <p id="paragraph"></p> no-repeat center center fixed;

But this does not give any results.
How i can use backimage variable correctly?

document.body.style.background=\url(${backimage}) no-repeat center center fixed`;`

from your code, i will believe image is a variable set somewhere, I used a free image link as image for example, all you need to do is include your own link and asset the background-image with JavaScriot


    var image = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713528199169-9488eb2d2b79?q=80&w=2787&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"; // Assuming 'image' is defined elsewhere
 var backimage = image;
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// Set the background image of the body element
document.body.style.background = `url(${backimage}) no-repeat center center fixed`;
 });




It could be because you didn't set a size for the <p> tag.
Try to do it like this:
<p id="paragraph" style="width:150px;height: 150px;">no-repeat center center fixed;</p> 

In the script instead of background write backgroundImage.
And pay attention to set the image as it is important to you that they see it. If you want for example to see the whole image set in the script in addition:
style.backgroundSize= "contain";

If something is not clear enough, ask.
